# Dataprovider can get connection from setUp

Tags: phpunit

#### Connect to database by setUp() failed

```
class ChanTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $db;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->db = new Core\Database('unitest');
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider testProvider
     */
    public function testData($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($a + $b, $c);
    }

    public function testProvider()
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `units`');

        return $this->db->rows();
    }
}
```

#### Connect to database by itself works

```
class ChanTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $db;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->db = new Core\Database('unitest');
    }

    public function testData($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `units`');

        foreach ($this->db->rows() as $item) {
            $this->assertEquals($item['a'] + $item['b'], $item['c']);
        }
    }
}
```

If I connect database by dataProvider through `setUp function`, it response `Fatal error: Call to a member function query()`, but if connect to database by itself works, can `dataProvider` get the `setUp function`'s setting?

Answer (score 29):

This is by design: In order to determine the number of tests, PHPUnit runs dataProviders before actually running the tests (and the setUp method).

From the [manual on DataProviders](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers):

> Note:
>   All data providers are executed before both the call to the setUpBeforeClass static method and the first call to the setUp method. Because of that you can't access any variables you create there from within a data provider. This is required in order for PHPUnit to be able to compute the total number of tests.

In your case I'd use a singleton/instance pattern for the DB.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is with [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```php
public function test_foo( $var_name ) {
    var_dump( 
        self::${ $var_name } // This is the same as `self::$bar`.
    );
}

public function data_foo() {
    return array(
        array(
            'bar', // This is a _string_ containing the _name_ of the variable, not the variable itself. 
        ),
    );
}
```

Your data provider passes the *name* of the variable, and the test function uses that to access the static member directly.

Comment: I went with this approach and it works

Answer (score -1):

Try overriding the constructor:

```
public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
{
    $this->db = new Core\Database('unitest');
}
```