# Laravel PHPunit Dataprovider error 'The data provider specified is invalid'

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am using dataprovider and data is fetched from database:

```
public function logoProvider()
{

    $result = Event::inRandomOrder()->select('id')->whereNotNull('logo')->first();

    return [
        [$result->id, '<path>'],
        ['', ''],
    ];
}
```

But getting below error:

```
The data provider specified for Tests\Unit\****Test::testLogo is invalid.
Error: Call to a member function connection() on null
```

Any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using factory in PHPUnit provider fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139843/using-factory-in-phpunit-provider-fails)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and manage to get a workaround by calling `parent::setUp();` explicitly inside the data provider.

So in your case,

```
public function logoProvider()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $result = Event::inRandomOrder()->select('id')->whereNotNull('logo')->first();

    return [
        [$result->id, '<path>'],
        ['', ''],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Wonderful this saves my day!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank they for their question. In my humble opinion and with all due respect Truly Theys!, the error message posted:

> Error: Call to a member function connection() on null

appears to me is likely caused by a hidden database-access-layer in the following call chain:

```
Event::inRandomOrder()->select('id')->whereNotNull('logo')->first()
```

And it looks to me as-if something like a hidden database-access-layer is not working (or is not ready) when the data-provider is called.

> Any solution?

With my impression of the error message in context of the data-provider excerpt, I'd assume that a potential solution could be to set up (configure) the database-access-layer before the call-chain.

It appears to me that the configuration is part of the overall *test fixture*.

---

- [Fixtures in the Phpunit Documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html)

---

When seeing this error message and given the configuration is part of the fixture, the solution is to set-up the fixture when the data-provider is executed.

According to *[Dataprovider can [*sic*] get connection from setUp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27287258/367456)* standard `setUp` and `setUpBeforeClass` hooks aren't applicable for data-provider methods.

Therefore an additional solution may be using the *bootstrap-file* Phpunit setting. Bootstrapping is done before running any test-case and data-providers that are bound to the global static state will find it configured.

---

- [XML Configuration in the Phpunit Documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html)

---

What would I consider as an alternative solution?

In my own experience - their mileage may vary - it appears often to me most straight forward and often sufficient to decide to test without a database connection first of all when using a data-provider in Phpunit.

When having a larger data-set for a test, the data-provider can easily get if from fixture files which are part of the test-suite and a file-system is normally available at least for read-access when running the test-suite.

---

- [Test Doubles in the Phpunit Documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html)

---

Any data-provider then just returns the plain test-arguments without making use of other expensive data layers and setups.

Recent versions of Phpunit also shuffle the order of the data provided, as the test-runner does for the order of how test methods are executed.

> See also the May 2020 edit in this [answer to *"Mocking PDO with phpunit"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31973908/367456).

That must not mean that there ain't specific tests that require a database adapter and a over-the-network serviced test-database (often called *integration tests* or *database tests*).

Tests requiring running with a database adapter are then done in a test-suite of it's own that can be run more dedicated to test the integration with the database adapter and as well with the connection to a database system.

The division is done because tests with a database connection are often much more expensive - in multiple ways: configuration/set-up, writing/maintaining the test and data with it and last but not least running the test - so that they can easily become a blocker in the fast feedback loop so they only execute them specifically dedicated towards a differently specific development goal (for example nightly).

Comment: It is not clear to me. Do I need get query data in setup?

Comment: You mean the setUp method? If you want to use the setUp method this is different from using data-providers. I think it also works (and IIRC is recommended(?) in Laravel Phpunit based testing), then just drop using data-providers is perhaps the way to go.